# PHP id value get without page refresh

Tags: php

I want to access php id on the same page for this i want something like this:

```
href="?id='.$row["id"].'"
```

but i want to show popup and not want the page to get refresh so i can show my result on my popup on the same page.

`href="#?id='.$row["id"].'"` // using hash will not make it work.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: do you want to $row['id'] of particular row from the table which is displayed

Comment: @Supriya Pansare yes yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue. Use this:

```
<a href="javascirpt:void(0)" rel='.$row["id"].' class="showpopup">

$(".showpopup").click(function(ev)
{   
      var getid = $(this).attr('rel'); // get id value
      alert(getid); // check to see if you are getting the value.
      ev.preventDefault();
}
```

thats it enjoy :)

Answer (score 1):

```
you can add a rel parameter to anchor tag and get that parameter using jquery or              javascript.

<a href="javascirpt:void(0)" class="item" rel="id_$row["id"]" />

$('a.item').click(function() {
var getvalue = $(this).attr('rel');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Parameter preceded by `#` will not reach the server-side script. That can be accessed only by Javascript.

Comment: yes thats true. but i don't know how to implement this using JS.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's true, the server doesn't get the anchor part. However there is a workaround using cookies. You can find it here: http://www.stoimen.com/blog/2009/04/15/read-the-anchor-part-of-the-url-with-php/